# Cut numeric with censoring in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I think this could already exist but I could not find. I am trying to cut numeric values. For example, I have a vector `x = c(rep(0,2),rep(1,2),rep(2,2),seq(3,5))`. With this vector, I just want to create a vector with factor having 4 levels. With the data, my expecting outcome is `(0,0,1,1,2,2,+2,+2)`. I was trying to use `cut` function but do not know how to create `+2`. 
I can do it with `ifelse` but I want to create it with `cut` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, show what you tried and we can help you debug.

```
cut(x, breaks = c(seq(-0.5, 2.5, by = 1), Inf), labels = c("0", "1", "2", "2+"))
# [1] 0  0  1  1  2  2  2+ 2+ 2+
# Levels: 0 1 2 2+
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have used Inf. Got it